# How can I make a alert call not to repeat on a button click?

Tags: jquery

My jsfiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/rDe9V/3/

**Relevant jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0)
    });
    $('form .create-playlist-button').click(function(e) {
        var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
        alert(title);
    });
});
```

**Requirement**

a.) When I click "New" I should be able to select corresponding form values like title, views etc

b.) Right now, it keeps on alerting on every keypress

I am new to jQuery and don't really know

Comment: -1 Well, what did you try? I see no use of the jQuery AJAX. Or perhaps the title just needs to be fixed to address the "real question" (of which I don't see, and hence the close vote as well) ..

Comment: my bad, SO was not letting me add question so I was trying anyway, I updated the question now

Comment: I am not getting any alerts on that fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [my update](http://jsfiddle.net/rDe9V/4/).

I used [.on()](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) instead of .live() and .click() as this works for all future elements in the page (like `live` but *better*). Also, I added the handler function to the `submit` event of the form, because that is what gets triggered when you click on the "New" button (right now this applies to all forms within your body, so you might want to narrow that selector down a bit).

In that handler you can get everything you need and submit that to the server using the [.post()](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.post) function. I think this is what you want.

Find the relevant piece of code below.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // activate "New" buttons if input is not empty
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $(this).next("button").prop('disabled', val.length === 0);
    });

    $("body").on("submit","form",function(e){
        // do not submit the form
        e.preventDefault();

        // handle everything yourself
        var $form = $(this);
        var title = $form.closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
        var entryTitle = $form.find('.input-small').val();
        console.debug(title);
        console.debug(entryTitle);
        // send the data to the server using .ajax() or .post()
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a way to check console log on JSFiddle by any chance?

Comment: Just open the console in Firebug/DevTools. The fiddle code gets executed in the right context.

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you for the explanation, it really helps me in understanding `jQuery` better